# for loop to update dictionary is only returning last value

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Let's say I have a list of urls. I want to append those urls to a value in a dictionary key and return the results of that key one at a time.

For example:

```
list_of_urls = ['www.superoranges.com','www.ilovetoeat.com']
parameters = {}
for url in list_of_urls:
    parameters = {'website': url}
print(parameters)
```

This only returns `{'website': 'www.ilovetoeat.com'}`.

Why is only the last value of the list being printed?

The bigger picture of of what I'm trying to do is update the the parameters in an API request with the websites from that list. So ideally I'd like to append those urls to a parameter, pass that down to a GET request and then move on to the next website and append that to the parameters in a GET request as well.

Comment: just do: `parameters = {'website': list_of_urls }`

Comment: You assign the first URL to the key 'website', first, after which the second URL overwrites the first.

Comment: Because you're looping on `list_of_urls` and only the last value is being assigned to `website` at the end of the loop. You can remove the loop and only do `parameters = {'website': list_of_urls}`. Now you can access to single URL by, `parameters['website'][0] # for the first list item`

Comment: If you're referring to the `print`, it's because it's only printing the latest value stored in your variable `parameters` after the code finishes running the `for` loop.

Comment: You completely overwrite your entire dictionary with `parameters = {'website': url}`, not just this one key-value pair. Checkout the `update` method of the dictionary class. Alternatively, assign to another key.

Comment: Ahh got it. Thanks so much for all of your help! I ended up figuring out what I was doing wrong. I didn't really even need to be updating the parameters. Regardless, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a list of dictionaries.

```
list_of_urls = ['www.superoranges.com','www.ilovetoeat.com']
parameters = []
for url in list_of_urls:
    dict = {'website': url}
    parameters.append(dict)
print(parameters)
```

Result:

> [{'website': 'www.superoranges.com'}, {'website':
> 'www.ilovetoeat.com'}]